# replace multi-index level column name based on condition of another level in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to replace column header in one level with a condition on another level. Specifically, if the label of second level column index is 'x', I want to change the first level column index to 'test'. The input and goal output is below along with a mask I have to select the columns that I do want to change. But I cannot rename in them inplace. Any advice would be nice. Thank you

```
# data I have
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['18', '13', '42','25'], ['a','b','c','d'],['x','y','z','x']])))
orig_dat = pd.DataFrame (([0, 2, 3,4],[0, 2, 3, 4]), columns = idx)
```

```
# desired output
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['18', '13', '42','25'], ['test','b','c','test'],['x','y','z','x']])))
goal_dat = pd.DataFrame (([0, 2, 3,4],[0, 2, 3, 4]), columns = idx)
```

```
# mask to select columns that need changing
mask = orig_dat.loc[:,orig_dat.columns.get_level_values(level=2).str.contains('x')].columns.get_level_values(level=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
# Iterate the orig_dat columns, check if the last element is 'x', then create a new tuple with 2nd element as 'test', otherwise leave as is
In [321]: new_cols = [(i[0], 'test', i[-1]) if i[-1] == 'x' else i for i in orig_dat.columns ]

# Create a MultiIndex object from above list and assign it to columns of orig_dat
In [330]: orig_dat.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)

In [331]: orig_dat
Out[331]: 
    18 13 42   25
  test  b  c test
     x  y  z    x
0    0  2  3    4
1    0  2  3    4
```

**EDIT:** After OP's comment to check if `x` is contained:

```
In [338]: new_cols = [(i[0], 'test', i[-1]) if 'x' in i else i for i in orig_dat.columns]

In [330]: orig_dat.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)

In [331]: orig_dat
Out[331]: 
    18 13 42   25
  test  b  c test
     x  y  z    x
0    0  2  3    4
1    0  2  3    4
```

Comment: Thanks @mayank! I realised I have another issue - it needs to work if x is contained in the label. I tried editing tie =='x' to .contains('x') but i am getting an error. Do you know how to append your code for this example ?  `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['18', '13', '42','25'], ['a','b','c','d'],['ax','y','z','bx']])))
orig_dat = pd.DataFrame (([0, 2, 3,4],[0, 2, 3, 4]), columns = idx)` thanks again!

Comment: @nac Please check my `EDIT` portion. Check how I define `new_cols` now. `contains` is a method to be used in `pandas`, in plain python you can use `in`.

Comment: oh of course perfect thanks so much. I had to change your new_cols to the following `new_cols = [(i[0], 'test', i[-1]) if 'x' in i[-1] else i for i in orig_dat.columns]` as the index was missing in the i in the in statement. Thanks so much!!